# Is it possible to find out from which module a class instance come from?

Tags: python, class, module, instance

I would like to know if it is possible to obtain the module name and directory path from a class instance of that module.
I need that because I save a class instance with pickle and I need to know from where this class come from when I load it from another software (on the same computer).

### update

So I tried the aswer of @albar

```
>>> from Models import Model_physio_moyen
>>> b = Model_physio_moyen.pop_Sigmoid_outside_noise
>>> module_name = sys.modules[b.__module__].__name__
>>> module_name
'Models.Model_physio_moyen'
```

So that working except if the class has been compiled with `jitclass`of `numba`:

```
>>> from Models.Pops_Stim import ATN
>>> a = ATN.pop_ATN()
>>> module_name = sys.modules[a.__module__].__name__
>>> module_name
'numba.jitclass.boxing'
```

In this condition, I wish I could find `Models.Pops_Stim` but I'm getting 'numba.jitclass.boxing'instead.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your instance is called `a`:

```
import sys
module_name = sys.modules[a.__module__].__name__
module_file = sys.modules[a.__module__].__file__
```

Comment: Ok, well that's working but not if the class was compiled with `jitclass`. I updated my question. I don't know if I can recover the module name in that condition though.